# If $M[G] \subseteq M[H]$ are forcing extensions, why is $M[H]$ a generic extension of $M[G]$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

I know that, wlog, we may assume $G = H \cap A$ for some complete subalgebra $A$ of the complete Boolean algebra $B$ over which $H$ is $M$-generic.

Comment: It's a theorem, it's nontrivial, and it has a proof in many places. Have you read the proof, what was your difficulty with it?

Comment: Jech mentions it without proof. He handwaves a couple sentences around it, and it was confusing. I know I'm supposed to consider $B$ as isomorphic to an iterated forcing, but I couldn't work it out.

Do you happen to know of a proof online?

Comment: Have you looked at other possible sources, like Jech or other books that explain forcing?

Comment: It's not in Jech, which is the set theory book that I have. Jech only mentions it and handwaves a couple sentences around it. I looked through an online copy of Kunen's textbook and couldn't find it there either. Any other suggestions, ideally for online resources?

Comment: I think it is in Jech. See page 269. Just before Theorem 16.4.

Comment: @William: That's the iteration, it's the other direction. This theorem is Lemma 15.43 and a few preceding statements (p. 248)

Comment: @Asaf no William was right; it is you who refer to the other direction. The part to which William referred is the handwaving to which I referred. I just couldn't figure out the isomorphism he claims exists. Probably missing something silly, but I find [D : B] enignmatic, and it doesn't even make sense to me that an isomorphism could exist.

Comment: I probably should have posted Jech's words in my original question and asked for help on that isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Just for humor value, here's a poset-based proof (all the proofs I've seen have been Boolean algebra-based):

Let $G$ be $\mathbb{P}_1$-generic over $M$, and $H$ be $\mathbb{P}_2$-generic over $M$. Let $\nu$ be a $\mathbb{P}_2$-name such that $\nu[H]=G$.

We can define a subset $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{P}_2$ as follows:

- $\mathbb{Q}_0=\{p\in\mathbb{P}_2: \forall q\in \mathbb{P}_1\setminus G, p\not\Vdash q\in G\}\cap \{p\in\mathbb{P}_2: \forall q\in G, p\not\Vdash q\not\in G\}$.
- $\mathbb{Q}_\lambda=\bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda}\mathbb{Q}_\alpha$ for $\lambda$ limit.
- $\mathbb{Q}_{\alpha+1}=\{p\in\mathbb{Q}_\alpha: \forall D\in M\text{ dense open subset of $\mathbb{P}_2$, $\exists p'\le p(p'\in\mathbb{Q}_{\alpha}\cap D)$}\}$.
- $\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}_{\vert\mathbb{P}\vert^+}$. *Note that this is just $\bigcap_{\alpha\in ON}\mathbb{Q}_\alpha$, for cardinality reasons.*

Basically, we take $\mathbb{P}_2$ and we "carve out" all the conditions that could force $\nu\not=G$. **Note that this process takes place in $M[G]$.**

It's now not hard to show that $H$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-generic over $M[G]$.

---

The construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a construction which I suspect has been introduced before, but which I haven't seen; see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227937/reverse-engineer-forcing-am-i-reinventing-the-wheel.