# A poset oriented proof for the intermediate model theorem.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The intermediate model theorem:

> If $M\subseteq N\subseteq M[G]$ are all models of $\sf ZFC$, with $G$ generic over $M$, then $N$ is a generic extension of $M$, and $M[G]$ is a generic extension of $N$.

The proofs I've seen (Jech lemma 15.43 and in Grigorieff's  "Intermediate submodels and generic extensions in set theory") are somewhat roundabout, as they pass through complete boolean algebras. Is there a more "direct" proof using just posets?

Furthermore, given some poset $P$, a generic $G$ and $M\subseteq N\subseteq M[G]$, the theorem gives me some $Q\in M$ and $Q$-generic filter $H$ such that $N=M[H]$. I want to understand $Q$ in terms of $P$. What can I say about it? Can I construct it more or less explicitly?

Comment: Also, both Jech and Grigorieff force using Boolean algebras. Try looking for the theorem in a source that doesn't. Like Kunen or Halbeisen.

Comment: Note that every forcing can be embedded into a collapse of some large enough piece of the universe to be countable. But while the collapse poset is *very* easy to describe, these embeddings are not.

Comment: I'll check Kunen. But are you implying that this might be hopeless?

Comment: P.S I thought maybe there's something like this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1607749/63762 just on the other direction

Comment: Oh, there is probably a poset-based proof. But I doubt there is one that will make you go "Ohhhhhh!!!!!!" in any meaningful way. At best, it will make you go "Well, that's a poset-based proof alright..."

Comment: Well, skimming through Kunen and Halbeisen I did not find this fact whatsoever.

Comment: Try asking Menachem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41361/discussion-between-ur-ben-ari-tishler-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: Let's not. I don't quite like the chat here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Noah Schweber posted a solution to this problem on MSE in the last 6(?) months. However, a quick search didn't reveal it.

Comment: @Stefan are you talking about this? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227937/reverse-engineer-forcing-am-i-reinventing-the-wheel  or the one I linked above?